# Searching in files and displaying matching directories in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We index documents in elasticsearch, and documents can be collected inside folders. Any document can be placed under multiple folders.

We want to search through the documents and list the folders which contains the matching documents.

I indexed documents and put the folders as nested objects right now, I thought terms aggregation would do it however elasticsearch doesn't support pagination of aggregations.

So how to handle this in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, ElasticSearch `terms` aggregation doesn't provide pagination. If your business logic requires it, you can specify `size` equal to `limit + offset` and remove unnecessary buckets on the client side